# Jackrabbit. Show nodes path in the file system

Tags: jackrabbit

I have a Jackrabbit repository running in tomcat. I am using `FileDataStore` to save my data and `BundleFsPersistenceManager` to save nodes' properties and configuration. My configuration files are:

**repository.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 1.4//EN"
"http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-1.4.dtd">

<Repository>
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
                <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
    </FileSystem>

    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
                <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleAccessManager" />
                <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.SimpleLoginModule" />
    </Security>

    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default" />
    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">

            <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
                        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}" />
            </FileSystem>

            <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
                     <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
            </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>

    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/versions">

        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
                         <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/versions" />
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager"/>

    </Versioning>

    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
        <param name="minRecordLength" value="100"/>
    </DataStore>
 </Repository>
```

**workspace.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace name="default">
    <!--
        virtual file system of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the FileSystem interface
    -->
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
    </FileSystem>
    <!--
        persistence manager of the workspace:
        class: FQN of class implementing the PersistenceManager interface
    -->

            <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager">
                    <param name="blobFSBlockSize" value="0"/>
                    <param name="minBlobSize" value="4096"/>
                    <param name="errorHandling" value=""/>
    </PersistenceManager>


    <!--
        Search index and the file system it uses.
        class: FQN of class implementing the QueryHandler interface
    -->
    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
</Workspace>
```

I have the following node structure:

root -> images -> test1 -> img1.png

However the worskpace items folder contains:

[image: workspace items folder]

I want to see root, images, test1 folders in that folder. Is that possible? Is there any configuration to achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: You must do tha by code! It's not possible to see that with folder structure

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do only by using jcr APIs